# bash download file does not work

Tags: bash, curl, sharepoint

I'm trying to download a file from a sharepoint via curl on Mac OS.

This is my command:

```
curl --user $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -O https://mysharepointaddress.com/filepath
```

and this is the output on terminal:

[image: output]

The problem: the command only writes response "401 unauthorized" in this file.

Does someone have some ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Note: installing and using external tools is no option because it need to run on several Macs

Comment: Could you share those 16 bytes?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov thanks for your hint. I checked the file with an Editor and updated the question

Comment: Try to quote the variables: `"$USERNAME:$PASSWORD"` (actually, you should always quote variables)

Comment: do `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` have the correct values? if you just try to echo `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` do they show the correct values? If you try to type it full like `curl -u user:pass -O https://..` does it download the file then?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I tried `"$USERNAME:$PASSWORD"` and `"$USERNAME":"$PASSWORD"` - same result as before
@Robert I also tried yours but I get same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Company Sharepoints often use Windows authentication. You have to set `--ntlm` and write the domain before the username like `MYDOM/username`. I don't know if your Sharepoint is behind a proxy but if it is, dont forget to use `--proxy`

```
curl --ntlm --proxy [ProxyHost]:[ProxyPort] --user [UserDomain]/$USERNAME:$PASSWORD -O https://mysharepointaddress.com/filepath
```

Let me know if it helped you.